# Jīvamukti in the ribhu Gita

Tags: shiva, worship

In a YouTube video, I heard that a jivamukti is only going to be endowed with knowledge if he worships the lord in accordance with the scriptures. Can anyone verify this is what the work says? I tried finding that part online, I do not have the Gita myself, but I couldn’t find it. Also another question: how do you worship Ishvara as per injunctions of the scriptures?

Comment: This is the video. Now I don’t know whether this guy Ramana Maharshi added this sentence or not. https://youtu.be/XPWU0-Lh3kY

Comment: Can you tell the timestamp at which it is said in the shared YouTube video?

Comment: 9:07 minutes, at the end

Answer (score 1):

Krishna lays out in *Uddhava Gita*, Chapter XXII how worship is to be conducted. In one of the last verses of the chapter, however, the Lord says (Swami Madhavananda translator):

> 53. By worshiping Me with devotion, regardless of any other consideration (such as going to heaven, etc.) he verily attains Me. This devotion is accessible to him who worships Me in this way (by *kriyayoga* i.e. ceremonials etc.).

And in Bhagavad Gita 2.42-45 the Lord says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> O Partha, no resolute and unwavering thought is formed in the minds of those who are deeply attached to pleasure and power; who allow their discrimination to be stolen away by the flowery words of the unwise; who permit their souls to bee ridden with desires; who regard the attainment of heaven as the highest goal, and who take great delight in quoting the panegyric texts of the Vedas [ritualistic section] and declare that besides these there is nothing. These texts promise rebirths as the reward of their action and lay down specific rites for the attainment of pleasure and power.
>
> The Vedas deal with the three gunas. Be free, O Arjuna, from the three gunas...

And further in Gita Chapter 9:

> 26. Whosever offers Me, with devotion, a leaf, a flower, a fruit, or water--that I accept the pious offering of the pure in heart.
> 27. Even the most sinful man, if he worships Me with unswerving devotion, must be regarded as righteous; for he has formed the right resolution.
> 28. He soon becomes righteous and attains eternal peace. Proclaim it boldly, O son of Kunti, that My devotee never perishes.
> 29. For those who take refuge in Me, O Partha, though they be of sinful birth--women, vaisyas, and sudras--even they attain the Supreme Goal.

and in Gita Chapter 12:

> 8. Fix your mind on Me alone, rest your thoughts on Me alone, and in Me alone you will live hereafter. Of this there is no doubt.

And *Mundaka Upanishad* III.ii.3 says:

> This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the Vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory.

The one thing that is needed is yearning. Through yearning, devotion comes. Through devotion, the Lord comes.